# In Odi ( oracle data integrator) , export columns with quotes with odisqlunload

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

by odisqlunload, how can i export csv file from oracle db with quoting(") varchar, char datatypes column? (Odi12c)
I mean, i just want to add a character prefix and suffix on column.

> Col1 col2 col3
> "B" ; 5 ;  "e"

Answer (score 1):

Giving the fact that you are connecting to an Oracle Database, you could do a query that will concatenate the desired prefix and suffix on your column/s and put that query in the SQL Query parameter.

Example:

```
Select '"' || 'B' || '"' as col1, 5, '"' || 'e' || '"' from dual;
```

UPDATE 1: you can't use the above solution when your columns have already maximum varchar value (varchar2(4000)).

Because of this impediment, I think that you can't use OdiSqlUnload to export your data into files, but you can use some KM that writes into files. So, the next suggestion is to create a mapping that uses some KM that writes into file, like:  IKM SQL to File Append

Comment: I had already done same method like your answer as a workaround. However, there are some column values (varchar2(4000) )  consisting 4000 length text :).